# File and folders Right click menu is open very slow

Tags: windows-10-v1511

I'm running windows 10 build 1511 with all latest updates.

When right click on a file , folder or shortcut , the menu is open very slow.

When right click On desktop , recycle bin , and other system icons the menu is open instantly.

How can i fix this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I have tested several things , on windows registry , device manager..etc.
And accidentally , i've found that all this problem is caused by Floppy Disk.
I've disabled Floppy Disk controller in Device manager , and now right click menu is open instantly.

I don't know why , but the problem is resolved